# Mapped drive simultaneously exists and doesn't exist?

Tags: windows-10, mapped-drive

I have a coworker who's mapped drive situation looks odd.

It looks like this -

[image]

But clicking on them, they do work, she can see the folders correctly on our NAS.

However, an application that we use looks to see if a map drive exists with a python `os.exists` type of test, and it doesn't see that P: exists.

They tried right-clicking and disconnecting and told me `it says the network connection doesnt exist`.

I had her run `net use P: /delete` and she got the message `The network connection could not be found`.  So then I had her try to then remake it thinking it was deleted, with a `net use P: \\192.168.1.200\FolderBay1\SomeFolder` and then she got the error `System error 85 has occured.  The local device name is already in use`.

It's like this drive both exists and doesn't exist.  Has anyone else experienced this and know what is going on or how to rectify it?

Comment: Try using the full UNC path in place of a drive letter. On Windows machines, make a desktop shortcut using the UNC path. This is the well-known quantum drive issue, where it's state is indeterminate until it is observed ;-)

Comment: they may have been mounted using e.g. psexec and one would need to follow the same procedure to unmount them. As far as them showing as unmounted, they may be showing this way because they are marked as persistent and get set before the network is up on (re-)boot. It isn't uncommon for a server connection to be severed and brought back up and the drive presents this way even when it can be browsed. ( for discussion about psexec see for example https://serverfault.com/questions/426288/permanently-mount-network-share-without-the-need-for-log-on-windows )

Comment: For network shares it's important to know whether the share was created in Administrator mode or not. Try the `net /delete` in both modes.